# Magento change language by login

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm searching now for hours. I try to switch the store language after the login.

Given is:

- The id of the Store I want to switch too.
- The Event Observer is also done.

This is what I worked out the last hours

My Observer:

```
$customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
// Get the Store ID we want to switch too
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('distributor_read');
$mainLanguage = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT...');

$storeId = $mainLanguage[0]["store_id"];
if (!$storeId == null) {                
    $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
    // Here I have to switch by the store code
    return;
}
```

Would be glad if someone could help me out.
At least I need a method to switch the language or storeview, but I don't find any working MagentoAPI methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will tell you guys what I did for this case. I tried to get the `Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http` class, completely in vain.

So I kept going on my research and I found a solution.

I used:

```
header('Location: '. Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl().'/customer/account?___store='.$storeCode);
```

There we go, my on login observer just set the language.

edit:

To set a new header could cause some problems, because if just any piece of html is already rendered you can not set a new header.

I worked sth. else out:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('*/*');
$url .= "?___store=" . $storeCode;

$response = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse();

$response->setRedirect($url);
$response->sendResponse();
exit();
```

There is obviously still a problem, the exit shouldn't used in good software code, but a simple `return` does not work, it does not end or kill the observer action.
I still working on a solution to kill the observer in a right way. As I said the observer need to get killed to redirect the url.

Answer (score 0):

to Set the store id programatically

In the index.php file, (in your language specific folder), add the following:-

```
$store_id = 'your_store_id_here';
$mageRunCode = 'store view code';
$mageRunType = 'store';

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

I am suggesting you to create some temporary session variable from login action and read in index.php to set language pack and again unset it if your work has been done

Hope someone will find this information useful :)

Comment: Hey,
thanks for your help on this. But I have to ask, what index.php do you mean. I have my language folders in app/locale and they don't have a index.php included.

Comment: @Silom welcome, this scenario will use when you have different url for store if dont have different folder like https://testdomain.com/germany_store then please ignore that you can add it your main index.php